# Can I return to the USA as a tourist after living there illegally as a minor?

Tags: usa, overstaying, minors

I am 20 years old. I live currently in Mexico and have been living here for 9 years. My parents took me to the USA when I was a minor (1 year and a half) and stayed until I was about 12 years old. I lived with my mom and sister. We asked to leave the US and exited voluntary. I have graduated from middle school and high school. I have an internship in accounting. I have my own small business and a family with 2 kids. I have never had any issues with the law in Mexico or in the USA. Is there a way that they will deny me automatically a visa for having been to the USA illegally? I want to go to the USA for a 4-day vacation fishing.